# FFT analysis with JavaScript: How to find a specific frequency?

Tags: javascript, audio, fft, audiocontext

I've the following problem:
I analyse audio data using javascript and FFT. I can already write the FFT data into an array:

```
audioCtx = new AudioContext();
analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);
analyser.fftSize = 64;

var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
```

Every time I want to have new data I call:

```
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
```

The variable "audio" is a mp3 file defined in HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" src="test.mp3"></audio>
```

So far so good.

My problem now is that I want to check if the current array "frequencyData" includes a specific frequency. For example: I place a 1000 Hz signal somewhere in the mp3 file and want to get a notification if this part of the mp3 file is currently in the array "frequencyData".

In a first step it would help me to solve the problem when the important part of the mp3 file only contains a 1000 Hz signal.  In a second step I would also like to find the part if there is an overlay with music.

Answer (score 3):

`frequencyData` is an array of amplitudes and each element of the array basically represents a range of frequencies. The size of each range is defined by the sample rate divided by the number of FFT points, 64 in your case. So if your sample rate was 48000 and your FFT size is 64 then each element covers a range of 48000/64 = 750 Hz. That means `frequencyData[0]` are the frequencies 0Hz-750Hz, `frequencyData[1]` is 750Hz-1500Hz, and so on. In this example the presence of a 1kHz tone would be seen as a peak in the first bin. Also, with such a small FFT you probably noticed that the resolution is very coarse. If you want to increase the frequency resolution you'll need to do a larger FFT.

Comment: I think thats only partially true! I figured out that if the FFT size is 64, you get 32 bins. So the array is half of the size. And from this half size only the first half is relevant, because we cant hear frequencies over 20000 Hz. The only thing I still miss is what kind of data the array contains. I know that it contains numbers from 0 to 255. But do these numbers specify loudness?

Comment: Loudness compared to another number in the array and not absolute loudness of course!

Comment: If the frequency data returned by your library is only half of the FFT size you specified then the frequency data your FFT library has returned is the frequency data between 0Hz and Fs/2, where Fs is the sampling frequency.If the input to a FFT function is real (such as is the case with audio) then a full frequency spectrum can be reconstructed from the frequency data in the the region 0Hz to Fs/2 so additional samples are not needed.Note that the spacing between frequency bins will still be Fs/(FFT Size) as jaket has stated.

Comment: The numbers you get from the FFT method represent the amplitude of particular frequencies in the audio and not really the loudness.Strictly speaking, loudness is a perceptual quantity and different frequencies are percieved differently by the ear and so you have move from the standard frequency scale to a perceptual scale such as the MEL scale before you can properly analyse the loudness of components.Practical though, you can just assume the amplitude to represent the loudness of different frequecies and just use it for many applications such as audio visualisations.